# GROUP BY time interval of X days, from a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to group data by a time interval of X days, starting from a specific date.  I know how to group it by days, weeks, months, etc., but I'm stumped for arbitrary time intervals.

For instance ... given a SQL table with `timestamp` and `session_count` columns, I'd like to generate aggregations grouped by a time interval (in this case, 30 days) from a specific date (in this case, today).

So, if today is `2015-08-31`, and I want to look back over the past 90 days, then I would expect to get three results, each covering a 30-day period:

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| start_of_interval | session_count |
+-------------------+---------------+
| 2015-08-01        |       1234567 |
| 2015-07-02        |       2345678 |
| 2015-06-02        |       3456789 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify an arbitrary number of days to use as the interval, and an arbitrary date to work back from.

*EDIT*:

This is the general approach I expect to need to use:

```
SELECT ROUND(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 2592000) * 2592000) AS thirtydays, 
SUM(session_count) AS session_count_sum
FROM my_table
GROUP BY thirtydays
```

But I'm not sure how to specify the start date from which we should be working back from in the `thirtydays` portion of the query.

Comment: you know that it is not a free code writing community, right?

Comment: Yes, I know.  I don't want anybody to write my code for me.  But pointing me in the right direction would be nice.  The basic question is: Is it possible to group by a time interval of X days, starting from a given date?  I'm sorry if the way I worded the question came off as asking other people to do my work for me.  I'll try to revise.

Comment: yes, it is possible, read about group by and mysql date functions

Comment: I'm familiar with both of them.  Frankly, if you think that hint is all I need, I'm not sure you fully understand my question.

Comment: please put a sqlfiddle together so we don't have to

Comment: @jawns317 Can you post a small sample of rows for us to test with? Probably the easiest approach will be to use month subtraction with a modulo 3 in the group by expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aggregates it in 30-day chunks:

```
SELECT 

FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            DAY, timestamp, '2015-08-31 00:00:00'
) / 30) AS thirtydays, 

SUM(session_count)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY thirtydays;
```

And this returns it with the start date of the interval:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2015-08-31 00:00:00', INTERVAL
    CEILING(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, timestamp, '2015-08-31 00:00:00') / 30
    ) * 30
DAY) AS thirtydays, 

SUM(session_count)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY thirtydays;
```